# How to find numbers from a list, the result are sequences based on a given number?

Tags: list, scala

Want a scala method, which can find numbers from a list, the result are sequences based on a given number:

```
def findSeq(baseNum:Int, numbers: List[Int]): List[Int]
```

If no numbers fit, just return `Nil`:

Given:

```
a number: 3
a list of number: 5,9,2,4,10,6
```

It will return:

```
List(4,5,6)
```

Explanation:

> Since the base number is 3, it will try to find 4 from the list. If found, try to find 5, then 6, until an expected one not found. The just return the found ones and sort it. Don't need to care duplicated numbers.

More test cases:

```
findSeq(3, Nil) === Nil
findSeq(3, List(3)) === Nil
findSeq(3, List(5,6)) === Nil

findSeq(3, List(4,5,7)) === List(4,5)
findSeq(3, List(4,7,6)) === List(4)
```

Looking for an elegant solution in Scala.

Comment: why return List(4,5,6) what's the logic?

Comment: First sort the numbers. Then, remove all numbers less than the `baseNum`. Then, starting with the first number in the list, keep adding additional numbers (in order) until the difference between the last number and the second to last number is not 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can simply use recursion like this:

```
def findSeq(baseNum:Int, numbers: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  if (numbers.contains(baseNum+1))
    (baseNum+1) :: findSeq(baseNum+1, numbers)
  else
    Nil
}
```

You method requires to be efficient (in some sense), or it's just for fun?

**NOTE**: btw, you could also use Stream, in case you don't care about efficiency. Something like this would do I guess:

```
def findSeq(baseNum:Int, numbers: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  Stream.from(baseNum+1) takeWhile (numbers.contains) toList
}
```

Comment: Good approach. Not require efficient because in my real program, the list is always small

Comment: Well, if the list is small, you can do something neater. See the edit.

Answer (score 1):

do a sort first, then foldLeft seems to be more efficient

```
def findSeq(baseNum:Int, numbers: List[Int]) = findSeqSorted(baseNum, numbers.sorted) 

def findSeqSorted(baseNum:Int, numbers: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
    numbers.foldLeft(List(baseNum))((acc,x) => if(x == acc.head + 1) x :: acc else       acc).reverse.tail
}
```